# Xcode displayed error while compiler start to compile

Tags: ios, xcode

I constructed one project. The dependency is managed via CocoaPods.
When ran the project. It occurred errors as below:

> Ld
>   /Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXueXi.app/iXueXi
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/zhaoxinqiang/Desktop/iXueXi
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACAlertController
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AliyunOSSiOS
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BACustomAlertView
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MJRefresh
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mantle
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Masonry
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reachability
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactiveObjC
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDAutoLayout
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDCycleScrollView
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TYPagerController
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TZImagePickerController
>   -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Desktop/iXueXi/Pods/JCore -L/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Desktop/iXueXi/iXueXi/Venders/AliPay -F/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/zhaoxinqiang/Desktop/iXueXi/Pods/AlipaySDK-2.0 -filelist /Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Intermediates/iXueXi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXueXi.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iXueXi.LinkFileList
>   -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Intermediates/iXueXi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXueXi.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iXueXi_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lACAlertController -lAFNetworking -lAliyunOSSiOS -lBACustomAlertView -lMBProgressHUD -lMJRefresh -lMantle -lMasonry -lReachability -lReactiveObjC -lSDAutoLayout -lSDCycleScrollView -lSDWebImage -lTYPagerController -lTZImagePickerController -lc++ -ljcore-ios-1.1.1 -lresolv -lz -framework AlipaySDK -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMotion
>   -framework CoreTelephony -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit
>   -weak_framework UserNotifications -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Intermediates/iXueXi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXueXi.build/iXueXi.app.xcent
>   -weak_framework NotificationCenter -framework SystemConfiguration -lresolv -lssl -lcrypto -framework MediaPlayer -framework AdSupport -lPods-iXueXi -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Intermediates/iXueXi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXueXi.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iXueXi_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/zhaoxinqiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXueXi-ddaxyfhwxiktmtgsfbafazqmdwlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXueXi.app/iXueXi
>
> ld: library not found for -lssl clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: 1) Make sure that you have opened the xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj. 2) Clean derived data and run again

Comment: You should learn how to ask question on stackoverflow, its not a good question.

Comment: It cannot solve the issue

Comment: I managed dependency via coco pods ,svn to source control, but I clone project and then pod install, then open workspace ,and build ,run,it display error ,no find library for -lssl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes after renaming a target or moving something, you can corrupt your pods installation. Luckily, there's an easier way to fix it than sudo make install's solution.

1. Run pod deintegrate to remove any trace of Cocoapods from your
   project.
2. Run pod install again to add it all back

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solution in My case go to xcode Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data  then clean this folder and run again. it worked for me.

Comment: I know ,did it more times but cannot solve it ..So ask here

Comment: It's not solution to solve it ..Looking forward to getting a replies ..

Comment: in my case this is solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem once and resolved it by removing duplicate items from Target. Find any duplicate folder or file in your project and remove all duplicate from Project. That will solve your problem.